# Sound board Swift 2

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to make a sound board app in swift and 3 out of the four buttons crash the app and the other one does nothing.
What am i doing wrong?
I am new to programming and i was trying to follow a tutorial but it doesn't work.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController  {

    let soundFilesname = ["Tacos", "What's that supposed to mean", "Cube fist man", "giraffe"]

    var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //set up audio player
        for sound in soundFilesname {

            do{

                //try and do somthing
                let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: "mp3")!)
                let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)

                audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
            }
            catch{
                //catch error that is thrown
                audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        //get the audioplayer thats corresponds to the button pressed

        let audioPlayer = audioPlayers [sender.tag]
        audioPlayer.play() 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

running the app through Xcode on my iPhone 5 IOS 9.0.2:

[image]

IOS simulator:

[image]

Comment: First fix your buttons place a print statement inside the button tapped method and check that is working - so all 4 buttons give you the response you want. Once you sort that figure out way the sound is not playing. Can you even play a simple sound ? i.e. just in view did appear ? Make sure all your sounds work. The go from there

Comment: Take a look at the other conversation on the post as i am having issues with the Xcode debugger

Comment: @DogCoffee yeah i press the button and get 0 to 3 on my four buttons but i push one and it freezes the app and i have to launch it again still no sound "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x1c" its a red bar over "audioPlayer.play()" when i tap the button

Comment: Can you play audio just with testing - i.e. in viewDidAppear ?

Comment: basics of what you are doing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKfe7xzHEZk

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the crash information that you are getting when tapping on button.

Also, put a print in buttonTapped to check correct tag no, might be you are accessing the out of bounds elements from array, but not sure unless you provide crash information.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
       // to check correct tag no
       print("Button tag is \(sender.tag)")

        //get the audioplayer thats corresponds to the button pressed
        let audioPlayer = audioPlayers [sender.tag]
        audioPlayer.play() 
    }
```

Comment: My app won't run in debug i don't know why it just hangs on the launch screen, i have to unplug it to get it to launch. So i can't provide crash information.

Comment: Is your app running in simulator? Is didFinush function calling? If you provide some information then we can figure out the issue.

Comment: I am using my iPhone 5 it will launch fine if i open the app from the home screen but threw Xcode it won't load past the launch screen ( text saying "now loading...") but in the simulator it just shows a white screen. i also get a "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.3" what ever that means as for the "didFinish" function i don't know. I haven't changed anything in the "AppDelegate.swift" file.

Comment: okay let me ask few things... Is your app running in iPhone 5? In your app delegate swift file, is your func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { } calling? Are you able to see your screen where you have buttons?

Comment: It will be nice if you send screen shot of the Xcode when you get crash

Comment: I can only see the buttons if i launch it on my iPhone from the home screen. If i run and build the app from Xcode i see my launch screen and it just stays there until i stop the app in Xcode or unplug my iPhone from my Mac then it launches and i see the buttons.

Comment: I see, it seems you have provisioning file issue when you run your app directly from Xcode... means.. if you have set adhoc provisioning file and try to run then Xcode wont run the app on device in debug mode... so now you have two problems... running app in debug mode and second your code crash on button tap... you can do one thing.. run your app on simulator and fix your crash then we can resolve provisioning issue.

Comment: it used to run fine in debug mode and it just stopped

Comment: let's discuss on skype narendar.singh.saini

Comment: sorry but i ran out of internet yesterday watching WWDC and plus I don't have Skype

Comment: not a problem... I always available on the internet... anytime you can download the skype and send me request and then discuss your problem.

Comment: ok thanks i copied everything to a new Xcode project and i now launches in debugger mode and now i get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x1c" its a red bar over "audioPlayer.play()" when i tap the button